# Why do I hear a "blip" at the end of an audio clip of a sinusoid?

Tags: discrete-signals, audio

I generated a [one second audio clip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3EzNZJ8qDe2Y3B3OTRCZ0tHWG8/view?usp=sharing) of a sinusoid at 440 Hz (16-bit, 44.1 kHz), ensuring that the last sample is zero. However, I hear a faint "blip" sound at the end of the clip, and have noticed this with similar clips that I have found online. Do you know why this happens, and how I can get rid of the "blip"?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If that's not a problem, properly window your sine wave, effectively adjusting its attack and release timing... or fade in fade out depending on the duration..

Comment: @Fat32 Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, but why do I need to window the sine wave in order to prevent the blip? Since the last sample is zero, I would expect the transition from non-silence to silence to be smooth.

Comment: No you don't have to window it. As you also point out, its natural transition to zero is also another way to decrease that blip. But windowing will also give you zero transition at the edges, irrespective of the sinusoidal phase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's still the first derivative discontinuity. That gives a blip with a -12 dB/octave decaying spectrum. It's less audible (because it has less high frequencies) than the -6 dB/octave decaying spectrum of a proper discontinuity, but still audible, especially with a subwoofer...

Do a (long enough a) fade out like Fat32 says and there will be no audible click.

Comment: Thanks! Now it's clear to me why the fade out is necessary.